# How to define a constant with more than one value in c#

Tags: c#, constants

the question looks like a bit silly, but I need to define a string constant with two possible long values...

for example:

BS_RUN_STAGE_SUCCESSFUL can be the code: 2010 and also 2110..

In this another case, the constant has only one:

```
BS_PROCESS_SUCCESSFUL = 2050

public const long BS_PROCESS_SUCCESSFUL = 2050;
```

any idea? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will the value decided at compile time or not ?

Comment: I Agree with the first sentence.

Comment: What is "another case"? Why can't you define 2 constants and use if do decide which one you want to use?

Comment: You cant specify more than one value to const,const is used to declare a constant field or a constant local

Comment: No Luke, I read the content from a log file...

Comment: Thanks to all of you.... MY MISTAKE... I dont know what i was thinking...

Answer (score 4):

`const` is a promise to the compiler saying : I won't change this value.
Therefore, you can only have one value to your `const` variable.

Since you said you want it to come from a config file, you could declare it as `readonly`, thus preventing any further modification once you set it after retrieving the config value.

```
public readonly long BS_PROCESS_SUCCESSFUL = yourMethodToRetrieveTheValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

the constant can have only one value and can't be changed even if you want to give its value on runtime